# IIS isn't propagating domain

Tags: web-hosting, iis

I called GoDaddy and verified my settings for the two IPs as follows.

```
ns1.asezo.com = xx.xx.xx.15
ns2.asezo.com = xx.xx.xx.16
```

Then I set the NAMESERVERs of `asezo.com` to the ns1/ns2 above, which GoDaddy tech support says is right.

When I try to visit my site, it says "Oops! Google Chrome could not find asezo.com".

When I try to ping the website, it gives me a time out.

I have the bindings in IIS for the default website as:

```
http - xx.xx.xx.15 - 80
www.asezo.com
```

and

```
http - xx.xx.xx.15 - 80
asezo.com
```

And I'm still getting nothing. I can go directly to the IP `http://xx.xx.xx.15/` and it gives me the IIS default website, I just can't get the url to propagate.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How long since you set the nameservers?

Comment: Last Thursday morning.

Comment: Can you post a link, it would be useful to check the actual DNS

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Do you mean to the website?  asezo.com is the url.

Comment: Sorry, it's unlikely that your domain would have itself as a nameserver (unless you set it up that way) - so I assumed godaddy was just using an unbranded nameserver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look a godaddy's [support article on nameservers](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/664) (though this isn't clear on what you're supposed to do with domains registered with them and hosted with them).

The information they have given you isn't correct, pinging ns1.asezo.com returns nothing, so there isn't a nameserver there. I would suggest calling support back.

Comment: Yup, the first person I spoke too apparently didn't know what I was asking. The second person fixed me right up. I just have to wait for it to propagate now.  Thx again.

Comment: @ErocM No problem mate, if you're happy with the answer please click the tick to accept it (Phone support can be a real nightmare) glad its getting sorted.